# Binding "§" key to button in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to bind key § to a function:

```
top.bind("§", lambda x: startRecognition(v, label2, top))
```

However, this binding with key § is not working. It is an actual key on Mac keyboard by the way.

Other keys on the keyboard are working with this code, so it is clearly a problem either with the key "§" itself or the symbol '§'. Anyone knows?

I'm using Sublime text editor by the way

Comment: How does one type this symbol? I'm on a Mac.

Comment: There's a key for that, at least in my mac keyboard. Like any other letter.

Comment: There is a key for that on [Mac *UK* keyboard](https://cdn3.macworld.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3504584/Mac-Keyboard_thumb800.jpg). Don't presume keyboards are equal across the globe :p

Comment: Alright. I'm on an American one. By the way, where is the approximate location of that key?

Comment: Yeah, that's true, sorry. It is on the left side, below the esc button and above the tab button, numbers start from the right and there's nothing on the left

Comment: French keyboard here, I don't see it either. It might be a good clue that you shouldn't use this key...

Comment: How about using `.bind("<Key>", printEvent)` to see what the event looks like when you press it?

Comment: .bind("<§>", printEvent) throws the following error: "_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "§"". I'm using python 3.6

Comment: I meant literally binding `<Key>` - this event type will catch all keypresses. You can then filter your key more narrowly with `event.keycode`, or `event.keysym_num`. But if you're really lucky, you'll get `event.keysym`, which you can use directly to bind it.

Comment: it prints the following: <KeyPress event keysym=section keycode=655527 char='§' delta=655527 x=-5 y=-50>

Comment: Nice. Then, does `.bind('<section>', ...)` work?

Comment: Yeah, it throws the same message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the appropriate binding for the [section sign key (§)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign) is `<section>`:

```
top.bind("<section>", lambda x: startRecognition(v, label2, top))
```

To discover it, we bound `<Key>` (any key), then noted the `event.keysym` from events that involved that key.